# How to select either but not both in Doctrine Collection?

Tags: doctrine-orm

In a Doctrine Collection, I have identical objects, each with an integer property '`player`' and another integer property called '`team`'. Player could be `1,2,3...` and Team can be `0,1,2,3,...` and so on. `0` means '`default team`'. All players belong to the default team first and foremost. A player can then become a member of other teams too. For example, player `2` can be a member of team `0, 2` and `3`.

Now, I would like to get the object where `Player 3` is a member of `Team 2`. If not, return the object where `Player 3` is a member of `Team 0`.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

What about filter method ?

```
// get all your player 3 data
$player3Collection = Collection->filter(function(ObjectType $object) {
    return ($object->getPlayer() == 3);
});

// then filter again or do other stuff ... 
if ($player3Collection->filter(///filter team callback///)->isEmpty() {
    throw new NoTeamException();
}

if ($player3Collection->count() == 1) {
    return $player3Collection->first(); // default team
}

// etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer using the collection's filter.

```
$team=2;

return $player3Collection
    ->filter(static function(Player $player) use ($team, $player3Collection){
        if($player->team===$team){
            return true;#/Got it
        } elseif($player3Collection->filter(static fn(Player $p) => $p->id===$player->id && $p->team===$team)){
            return false;#/A counterpart Player object with correct team exists in player3Collection, so skip it here.
        } elseif($player->team===0){
            return true;#/Fallback team record
        }

        return false;#/Exclude other teams
    });
```